# php - convert MySql query result to JSON

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to encode a MySQL query result to JSON, I'm using CodeIgniter.
Code:

```
public function fetch_all_users(){
         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('user');
         $query = $this->db->get()->result();

        foreach($query as $row){
            print_r(json_encode($row));
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
{"id":"1","name":"ropen"}{"id":"2","name":"codey"}
```

Desired Result:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"ropen"},{"id":"2","name":"codey"}]
```

I already tried searching the net but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Forget the foreach loop, `$query` already holds what you want so just do `echo json_encode($query);`

Comment: wow im such a noob lol thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the foreach loop, `$query` already holds what you want

```
public function fetch_all_users(){
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('user');
     $query = $this->db->get()->result();

     echo json_encode($row);
}
```